# problem in creation of nullable property in CodeFirst approach

Tags: asp.net-core

```
        .I created project with .net core 6. 
     GroupImageName is nullable but when I do migration, this property is created non-nullabe,also for example, posts property is created non-nullable.
```

### what is the problem?
How can I resolve it?

---

Comment: Please upload code in text instead in images. Images can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers, harder to read than text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a nullable properties from code first you have to use `Nullable<string>` or `string?` which makes your property nullable in database after migration

E.g. in your case your model looks like below:

**PostGroup.CS**

```
Public class PostGroup
{
   public int GroupId{get;set;}
   public string GroupName {get;set;}
   public string? GroupImageName {get;set;}
   .
   .
   .
   n so on properties
}
```

after making above change just run the command like below from `PMC`

```
add-migration
update-database
```

above stapes will make your properties nullable in db after successful migration